# macOS retrieving environment variables from kernel

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

is there away to use getenv from a kernel extension?
I'm guessing it's a user-mode function, but thought there might be an alternative.

Thanks

Comment: `sysctl` maybe?

Comment: I have checked sysctl, but couldn't figure out if it can be done with it.
I saw that only the PATH variable could be retrieved through it but that's it.

Comment: The answer is essentially no. If you edit your question to be higher level and tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you, however.